# numerically solving systems of coupled differential equations with multiple diffs in one eq in python

Tags: python, scipy

I am looking to mathematically model a complex system using python, however, I am fairly new to the latter.

My system consists of a set of coupled differential equations of the form

f1 = c1 * da(t)/dt + c2 * db(t)/dt + c3

f2 = c4 * dg(t)/dt + c5 * dh(t)/dt + c6

that I try to solve numerically.

I followed the SciPy Cookbook and aimed at using odeint for my program but now I am stuck on the fact that odeint requires an input of the form dx/dt and I can not rewrite my eqs into that form, the additional differential db/dt is not dependent on the da/dt and can't be cancelled out.

All the examples from the SciPy Cookbook seem to focus on either coupled differential equations of the form

f = c1 * x' + c2 * x'' + c3

or

f1 = c1 * x'

f2 = c2 * y'

Is there a recommended function or other library that accepts coupled differential equations of the form

f = c1 * da(t)/dt + c2 * db(t)/dt + c3

or is there a way to make odeint accept multiple differentials somehow?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Can't you make `x = a(t) = x` and `y = b(t) `, so `x' = da/dt` and `y' = db/dt`?

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  Can you write down the complete differential equations that you are trying to solve?  I think `f`, `f1` and `f2` are just your shorthand to indicate that the corresponding expressions are the right-hand sides of your equations.  If that is the case, you should instead write the full equations, with both the left and right sides explicitly stated.

Comment: If you mean to solve `c1 * da(t)/dt + c2 * db(t)/dt + c3 = 0`, well, that is one equation with two dependent functions.  It is underdetermined, and you can just integrate to get `c1*a(t) + c2*b(t) + c3*t = c1*a(0) + c2*b(0)` and then solve algebraically to get, say, a(t) in terms of an *arbitrary* b(t).

Comment: ODE integration expects either a scalar or a vector. In most cases you can transform a system of equations into a vector ODE. If that is not the case you probably can workaround to write it as an implicit function. Can you write down your system of equations?